# Firebase HTTP Cloud Function error 'Cannot GET /'

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get users data from firebase but I keep receive 'CANNOT GET /' error.

```
//firebase init
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

//express and cors init
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

//middleware init
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const database = admin.database();

app.get("/users", function (request, response) {
    return database.ref('/users').on("value", snapshot => {
        return response.status(200).send(snapshot.val());
    }, error => { 
        console.error(database);
        return response.status(500).send(err);
    })
});

exports.users = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I also try to use another function from another website I refer to get at least the username but it returns error.

```
exports.users = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
     database().ref('/merchants').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
       var username = snapshot.val().username;
       res.status(200).send(username);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Problem 1: Exporting express applications

When you export an `express` app through a Cloud Function, the paths become relative to the exported function name. You exported your app as `exports.users` which sets the root path of your function to `/users` and to call it, you would visit `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/users`.

However, because you defined a route handler for `/users` (using `app.get("/users", ...)`) as well, you added a handler for `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/users/users` instead.

The error `Cannot GET /` is thrown because when you call the function at `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/users`, the relative URL is set as `"/"`, which you haven't configured a handler for (using `app.get("/", ...)`).

So to fix your code above, change

```js
app.get("/users", function (request, response) {
```

to

```js
app.get("/", function (request, response) {
```

#### Problem 2: Username queries

The issue could be as simple as that you call `database()` instead of `admin.database()`.

However, the purpose of this query is unclear, so I will assume that you have a merchant's ID and you are trying to get the username of the owner of that particular merchant.

This would mean a data structure similar to:

```
{
  "users": {
    "somePerson": { ... },
    "otherPerson: { ... }
  },
  "merchants": {
    "reallyGreatGuyInc": {
      "username": "somePerson",
      ...
    },
    "realShadyPeopleInc": {
      "username": "otherPerson",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

If you exported a function called `getMerchantUsername` where you pass in the merchant ID via a GET parameter and call it at the URL `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/getMerchantUsername?id=reallyGreatGuyInc`, you would define it using the following code:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.getMerchantUsername = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (!req.query.id) {
      // '?id=' is required
      return res.status(400).send("Missing 'id' parameter");
    } else if (/[\u0000-\u001F\u007F\.\$#/\[\]\\]/.test(req.query.id)) {
      // check id for invalid characters
      return res.status(400).send("Invalid 'id' parameter");
    }

    // run query
    admin.database().ref(`/merchants/${req.query.id}/username`).once('value')
      .then((snapshot) => {
          var username = snapshot.val();
          res.status(200).send(username);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          res.status(500).send('Request failed.');
      });
});
```

Notes:

- The test for invalid characters is based on the list in the [RTDB: Structure data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree) documentation. This somewhat prevents looking at other database values.
- If you only need the value of username, rather than request the entire merchant object and parse it, request only the username as in the example above where I used `` `/merchants/${req.query.id}/username` ``.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and thanks for your explanation I am able to understand the problem better. But why the code in Problem 1 will return me only 1 record of users where as there are 6 users records in the firebase database. I tried to solve it using foreach of the snapshot but it return with error.

Comment: That code should return all the data below `/users` just fine. Make sure that the data you are looking at is actually under `/users` not something similar like `/user`.